# Help me create incenter-of-triangle problems involving a lot of whole-number lengths.

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm trying to create problems like this one:
[image]

But I want to create them so that the path shown from G to each other point has a whole-number length, and the distance between any two points shown on one side will also be a whole number.

I believe that one possibility is to make all of the small triangles shown, with a vertex at G, the same Pythagorean triple. For example, if all hypotenuses are 5 (GA=GB=GC=5) and GD=GE=GF=3, then the remaining distances from D, E and F to each adjacent vertex will be 4.

In other words, one possiblity is to make ABC equilateral.

I believe that that is the only possibliity. I believe that there's no way that all of the shown segments can have whole-number lengths except by making GA=GB=GC.

Is that right?

Comment: This will not work since the relation between the heights and the hypotenuse is 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was wrong, $u$ and $v$ are not arbitrary.

Let mark $GA=a$, $GB=b$, $GC=c$, $GD=GE=GF=r$. These numbers must satisfy following equation

$$\arccos \frac{r}{a}+\arccos \frac{r}{b}+\arccos \frac{r}{c}=\pi$$

Solving for $c$ gives

$$c=\frac{abr}{\sqrt{(a^2-r^2)(b^2-r^2)}-r^2}$$

This equation has many integer solutions with $a\neq b$.

For example, $r=2$, $a=3$, $b=18$, $c=3$.

Solutions with non-isosceles triangle ABC also exist:

$r=9$, $a=12$, $b=16$, $c=72$.

If you additionally require $AE=AD=\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$, $BE=BF=\sqrt{b^2-r^2}$ and $CD=CF=\sqrt{c^2-r^2}$ to be integer, this reduces number of solutions. But there are no equilateral triangles in solutions. Examples of such solutions are:

$r=21$, $a=35$, $b=35$, $c=75$ (isosceles) and $r=72$, $a=120$, $b=153$, $c=170$ (non-isosceles).

Comment: You can see picture of last solution in https://telegra.ph/file/33757b5ca65b1f47078f7.png

Comment: I'm impressed and grateful, but I need another day or two to think about how you find the whole-number solutions to your second equation, c=fraction.

Comment: I've made bruteforce on $r$, $a$, $b$.